# javascript how limit autoclick

Tags: javascript

I have this code for auto click, that clicked all inputs in page.

I want limit this function to numbers for example 10

```js
javascript:var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('_54k8 _56bs _56bt'); 
 for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) { 
 inputs[i].click(); 
 }
```

Comment: then replace `inputs.length` with your number

Comment: `i < inputs.length && i < 10`